# Inconsistent behavior when inserting a set into cells using .loc in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

It's a pretty simple example

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame()
value_to_be_set = {'1'}

df.loc[0, 'col1'] = value_to_be_set
df['col2'] = None
df.loc[0, 'col2'] = value_to_be_set

print(df.head())
```

output

```
   col1 col2
0    1  {1}
```

Why is the datatype different for both columns?

Python 3.7.3
pandas version: 0.23.4

Comment: .. i get a TypeError for `df.loc[0, 'col1'] = value_to_be_set`: `TypeError: len() of unsized object`.

Comment: Probably dependant on the version, I'm able to reproduce @wwii

Comment: .. perhaps - `'0.20.3'`.

Comment: Reproducing with `'1.0.3'` @wwii

Comment: This is strange behavior, would you like open a issue in github ?

Comment: I don't think it's that strange, same reason as explain in Serge's answer.

Comment: Yes this seems buggy indeed, doesn't look like there's a logical explanation behind it

Comment: I think `loc` shouldn't be allowed to use for creating rows/columns.

Comment: @yatu feel like it will make sense if the first assignment is same as the second one

Comment: OK, now it's pretty strange, when replaced `{'1'}` with `{1}`, both two columns are unpacked :-).

Comment: Yes, you can have different dtypes enforced when setting a new val in a col, depending on its dtype. But to have a set vs a string? Seems weird. Specially since both cols are `object` @wen

Comment: I'm getting them both unpacked to `df.dtypes: float64, object`, which would seem more reasonable I guess, since col2 is initiallized to object dtype? :) @QuangHoang

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In first assignment, you create a num_column from a set, said differently from an iterable. You ask for 1 single element and provide an iterable of size one, so you affect the content of the set to the single cell. You can try to use a set of 2 values to see that it would raise an error.

In second assignment, you update a cell in an existing column. Pandas has no reason to unpack anything here, and it affects the set to the cell.

To be honest, this *explains* what happens, but is not a justification for the rationale behind the different behaviours...

Comment: Yes but the way in which the first col and the third are set, is exactly the same. The only difference is that `col2` has previously been set all to `None`, which shouldn't modify the behaviour? Since in the first col the values are strings, and an object col is created, just like with col2

Comment: It' not the same. In one case, pandas is creating a column while setting its contents. In the other case, a column exists and pandas is trying to fit the data into that column.

Comment: Yes but I see those as independent processes? Sure the first involves creating a new col, but both are updating a single cell `df.loc[0, 'col1']` This just seems buggy to me @matt

Answer (score 3):

When you expand the `value_to_be_set` object to greater than one element, this error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#314>", line 1, in <module>
    df.loc[0, 'col1'] = value_to_be_set
  File "C:\Users\rook\Projects\Sandbox\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 671, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
  File "C:\Users\rook\Projects\Sandbox\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 850, in _setitem_with_indexer
    self._setitem_with_indexer(new_indexer, value)
  File "C:\Users\rook\Projects\Sandbox\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1019, in _setitem_with_indexer
    "Must have equal len keys and value "
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Whereas when you call it for `'col2'` after initializing the column, this doesn't occur.

Looking at my env source code for `__setitem__` on `1.0.3` reveals:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    if isinstance(key, tuple):
        key = tuple(com.apply_if_callable(x, self.obj) for x in key)
    else:
        key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
    indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
    self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
```

The last line of which has been changed to below in `1.0.4` current branch on github:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    # ... same as above ... #
    self._has_valid_setitem_indexer(key)

    iloc = self if self.name == "iloc" else self.obj.iloc
    iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
```

However the `_has_valid_setitem_indexer` seem to be still in the works:

```
def _has_valid_setitem_indexer(self, indexer) -> bool:
    """
    Validate that a positional indexer cannot enlarge its target
    will raise if needed, does not modify the indexer externally.
    Returns
    -------
    bool
    """
    if isinstance(indexer, dict):
        raise IndexError("iloc cannot enlarge its target object")
    else:
        if not isinstance(indexer, tuple):
            indexer = _tuplify(self.ndim, indexer)
        for ax, i in zip(self.obj.axes, indexer):
            if isinstance(i, slice):
                # should check the stop slice?
                pass
            elif is_list_like_indexer(i):
                # should check the elements?
                pass
            elif is_integer(i):
                if i >= len(ax):
                    raise IndexError("iloc cannot enlarge its target object")
            elif isinstance(i, dict):
                raise IndexError("iloc cannot enlarge its target object")

    return True
```

In any case, I would suggest submit this as a bug since it is still reproducible in the latest version `1.0.4`:

```
>>> df.loc[0, 'col1'] = v2
>>> df['col2'] = None
>>> df.loc[0, 'col2'] = v2
>>> df
  col1 col2
0    1  {1}
>>> pd.__version__
'1.0.4'
```

The absurdity is apparent if you insert the same item to a second index:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame()
>>> df.loc[0, 'col1'] = v
>>> df.loc[1, 'col1'] = v
>>> df
  col1
0    1
1  {1}
```

I would think using `loc` to set up new columns is buggy indeed due to implied unpacking.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame()
value_to_be_set = {'1'}

df.loc[0, 'col1'] = value_to_be_set
df['col2'] = None
df.loc[0, 'col2'] = value_to_be_set

print(df.head())
```

Here you in col1 you directly send the value like it takes the iterable like set and iterate through it to set value and there it find 1 as element and it set it.

where in 2nd case you set col2 with None and therefore in this case the whole set is taken as a element and set {1} as a value.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame()
value_to_be_set = {'1'}

df.loc[0, 'col1'] = value_to_be_set
#comment down
#df['col2'] = None
df.loc[0, 'col2'] = value_to_be_set

print(df.head())
```

After comment down the None the value of col2 is same as col1.

```
 col1 col2
0    1    1
```